# Match up/overlap arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have two lists, one of integers and one of tuples containing integers as follows (this is an example)

```
firstList = [4, 8, 20, 25, 60, 123]
secondList = [(0, 3), (4, 5), (7, 14), (19, 22), (40, 90), (100, 140)]
```

I am wanting to match up (overlap) the first array onto the second array as well as possible. For example:

The first section of the array `[4, 8, 20]` would match up with `[(4, 5), (7, 14), (19, 22)]` as those first numbers fall on or between the numbers in their respective tuples.

`25` would be ignored as there is no match for it

`[60, 123]` would then match up with `[(40, 90), (100, 140)]`

The above is fairly simple to implement however what I am getting stuck with is where there is an offset that throws everything off. Say `4` is subtracted from all the numbers in the first array so we are now left with

```
firstList = [0, 4, 16, 21, 56, 119]
secondList = [(0, 3), (4, 5), (7, 14), (19, 22), (40, 90), (100, 140)]
```

Some numbers still match up, however not all of them and now `21` falls within the range of `(19, 22)` when it should be ignored and a number of other numbers fall within the wrong ranges now. How can these new numbers still be matched up in the "best possible way" in other words in a fashion in which there are the most matches?

Ideally the method would figure out to add an offset back `4` and then match up the numbers again.

---

**Clarification edit**
The numbers and tuples will be ordered in ascending sequence (as seen above), any given number can't be matched with multiple tuples and any given tuple can't be matched with multiple numbers. It's 1 to 1.

The three things I am wanting returned from this are 1: The offset (4) in this case that gets things matched up the best. 2: What are the numbers that match up with a tuple and which tuple do they match up with. 3: What numbers don't match up in the best case scenerio (with the most matches).

Here's an illustration, I don't know if this will help though. Imagine a long piece of paper along a table with the number line. The sections indicated by the tuples have stripes of colour painted along them (each number section a different colours) painted along them (e.g. red strip from 0 to 3, purple strip from 4 to 5, etc). The areas that don't have any number section are left blank (or white)

Then you have a second paper (also with a printed numberline) placed above this first one with holes cut out at the given numbers in `firstList` Where should you slide this top numberline over the stationary bottom numberline so as to see colours in as many of the holes as possible ensuring that the same colour does not appear twice?

I don't know if that makes things any clearer - I hope it does!

Is there a library/algorithm or method for performing such a task apart from brute forcing it?

Comment: Please explain fully what the desired output for your example is. I understand how a number is matched with a tuple, but I don't understand why you would match `[4, 8, 20]`, instead of each of the numbers `4`, `8`, and `20`. Also, after a number matches with a tuple, can that tuple match with some other number as well, or is that not allowed?

Comment: See my edit - I hope I'm making things clearer.

Comment: You still haven't said anything about what the output format should be. Did you want a dictionary whose keys are the numbers in `firstList`, and whose values are the tuples from `secondList`? Or did you want something else?

Comment: That would be fine - but that really isn't the issue here. The issue is finding an efficient method for matching up the two arrays without going through every possibility.

Comment: Check out my answer. I haven't fully tested it yet, so let me know if there's an issue, and I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't fully defined, but here's something that makes sense to me:

```
def binSearch(x, L, low=None, high=None):
    if low is None: low = 0
    if high is None: high = len(L)
    if low==high: return None

    mid = int((upper+lower)/2)
    lower, upper = L[mid]

    if lower <= x <= upper: return mid

    if x>high: return binSearch(x, L, mid+1, high)
    return binSearch(x, L, low, mid)


def match(L, T):
    answer = {}
    for num in L:
        m = binSearch(num, T)
        if m is None: continue
        answer[num] = L[m]
        L.pop(m)
    return answer


def main():
    firstList = [4, 8, 20, 25, 60, 123]
    secondList = [(0, 3), (4, 5), (7, 14), (19, 22), (40, 90), (100, 140)]
    matches = match(firstList, secondList)
    for k in sorted(matches):
        print(k, "matches with", matches[k])
```